# Save entity directly after edit in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I use a `DataGrid` to visualise my data to the user. After an edit, the updated data should be stored directly to the database, without using any 'Save' button.

This is my solution so far, which works for all `DataGrid` columns but the `ComboBox` by using an `EventTrigger` to `InvokeCommandAction`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals, Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="EPC" Binding="{Binding Epc, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visual ID" Binding="{Binding VisualId, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Geschlecht" Binding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bucht">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource=
"{Binding DataContext.Pens,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:AdministrationView}}}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Pen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Pen.PenId}" 
                              SelectedValuePath="PenId"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

**How can I call the `SaveCommand` in my view model after the `ComboBox` selection was changed?**

Or is there an easier solution altogether to achieve my desired behaviour (auto save to data store after each edit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the desired behaviour if you just add another `EventTrigger` that activates your `ICommand` like that:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bucht">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Pens, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:AdministrationView}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Pen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="{Binding Pen.PenId}" SelectedValuePath="PenId">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:AdministrationView}}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel I assume you have your selected item defined like that?

```
object selectedPen; 
public object SelectedPen 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return selectedPen; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if (selectedPen != value)
        {
            selectedPen = value; 
            DoSave(); // insert saving logic here
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPen"); 
        }
    }
}
```

You could call the save when the value changed in the setter.

Comment: I'm not sure I could like it... Having the context (required for DoSave()) in the ViewModel. Usually I keep the saving logic in the user interface (and thinking about what will happen when you will use SelectPen next year I can understand why).

Comment: Sorry, what? What dou mean by _and thinking about what will happen when you will use SelectPen next year I can understand why_?

Comment: It's a personal opinion. If you usually don't use the ViewModel in this way, you could forget (or your collegue could not know) that it saves on property set. But is a personal opinion...

Comment: I agree with the opinion to try to minimize logic in getters/setters. But the context should be available in the `ViewModel` imo.

Comment: Yes, the view model has access to the context via a unit of work/repository pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to implement [IEditableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) on your ViewModel and implement `DataGrid.CellEditEnding` and `DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged`. 
See [this](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html) blog post from Colin Eberhardt for Details.

```
private DataRowView rowBeingEdited = null;

private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender,
                                  DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
    rowBeingEdited = rowView;
}

private void dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rowBeingEdited != null)
    {
        rowBeingEdited.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would introduce a very tight coupling between my viewmodel and my view, which I would like to avoid. I get the same results without the tight coupling by using the EventTrigger in my example code.

Comment: There is no coupling between View and ViewModel except the IEditableObject-interface. This is all codebehind acting on viewelements which implicitly calls the IEditableObject-Implementaion of the DataContext. You are mirroring the built-in funtionality of the DataGrid.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. No tight coupling indeed :-)

Comment: But I wonder if this solution is any different to the one I am using anyway. Right now my command fires after event 'RowEditEnding' (see my example code above).

Comment: With this solution you can apply the commit to every cell without the need to modify the template. In fact you could drop this code in a Behavior and reuse ist without much hassle. It is the solution with fewer points to maintain imo.